# reverse Googlefinance Values - I want descending from the newest to the oldest

Tags: google-finance

I want to get the list of weekly close Values of a Ticker. But they should begin with the newest date.

`=GOOGLEFINANCE(XYL; "price"; $F$31;HEUTE();"WEEKLY")`

or

`=GOOGLEFINANCE(XYL; "price"; HEUTE(); $F$31;"WEEKLY")`

show the same result. With this code I get the values, but the first colum is the value of the oldest date.

[image]

I want it to start with the newest Date. Is there a build in function that just flips the order of the List?

Best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you simply use SORT(range,1,false) for the info the GOOGLEFINANCE() displays? You can do a simple sort to a new range or to flip the google finance without moving anything around you would:

```
=SORT((GOOGLEFINANCE(XYL; "price"; HEUTE(); $F$31;"WEEKLY")),1,false)
```